# How do I tell vim that some file extensions are synonymous?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype

I edit C++ code in `.cpp` files, while template code goes into `.tcc` files. When I open such a file, no syntax highlighting is available. I tried `set syntax=cpp` in a a `tpp.vim` file in `~/.vim/ftplugin/`, but it does not do anything, while in the editor it works. Is there some way to have vim treat specific extensions as synonymous with others?

Comment: Very useful question! Thanks!!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The preferred approach is to create a `~/.vim/filetype.vim`, as mentioned in `:help 43.2` and explained in [Vim FAQ 26.8](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.8):

> A better alternative to the above approach is to create a filetype.vim
>   file in the ~/.vim directory (or in one of the directories specified
>   in the 'runtimepath' option) and add the following lines:
>
> ```
> " my filetype file
> if exists("did_load_filetypes")
>     finish
> endif
> augroup filetypedetect
>     au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.x       setfiletype c
> augroup END
> ```

---

**Edit:**

The `did_load_filetypes` shouldn't cause you any problems; it would only require a Vim restart after it is changed.

It is necessary in order to avoid multiple and unnecessary loading of this file, and it is inherited from the base file ($VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim):

```
" Vim support file to detect file types
"
" Maintainer:   Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
" Last Change:  2014 Jun 12

" Listen very carefully, I will say this only once
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif
let did_load_filetypes = 1
```

For more information check `:help new-filetype`.

Comment: Why the `if` statement? If I leave it in, the autocmds are not executed for me.

Comment: @oarfish even if you restart Vim?

Comment: Ok, this is weird. I have to `au!` statements in the group, namely `au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.py        setfiletype python` and in the line below
`au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.tpp       setfiletype cpp`. But only the second one actually works. Editing `.py` files does not set the file type to `python`. I'm not exactly a vim-guru so I'm probably missing something.

Comment: @oarfish if you check the file I mentioned on the edit you will find that it already contains a line with `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py,*.pyw  setf python`, so your first line is irrelevant. Your problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: `"Editing .py files does not set the file type to python"` - what is the output of `:set ft` on that case? If it is not python, try following the procedure in [Vim-FAQ 2.5 - I have a "xyz" (some) problem with Vim](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5)

Comment: Found the error! From some ancient time of vim noobism I head a `~/.vim/ftdetect/py.vim` file which set the filetype incorrectly. Removed it and it works.

Comment: Great solution! Perfect!! Thanks a lot! +1

Answer (score 26):

You could do (in your global `.vimrc`):

```
autocmd BufEnter *.tpp :setlocal filetype=cpp
```

Comment: `autocmd BufEnter *.cuf :setlocal filetype=fortran` to treat CUDA Fortran files as Fortran

Comment: If you have multiple files you want to associate with a language, delimit the patterns with commas and no spaces between the commas: `autocmd BufEnter *.tsx,*.jsx,*.ts :setlocal filetype=javascript`

Comment: Upvoted this answer because it works directly from the .vimrc file.

Answer (score 1):

One could also have: `au BufRead,BufNewFile *.tpp setlocal filetype=cpp` in their `.vimrc` such that upon opening a file with `.tpp` extension, filetype is set for *C++*

Comment: This seems to be basically identical to @edi9999's answer. Can you elaborate on why to use `BufRead,BufNewFile` instead of `BufEnter`?

Comment: @oarfish It doesn't matter too much I think, but I prefer `BufRead,BufNewFile` ahead of `BufEnter` because in the docs (`:help BufEnter`) it states: 
"BufEnter:  .... Also executed when starting to edit a buffer, **after** the BufReadPost autocommands." where _BufReadPost_ is synonymous with _BufRead_. 
In addition, I do not believe the `:` is required before `setlocal` so I also omitted that in my answer. (I might have interpreted this completely wrong, happy to hear further discussion)